# How to make an HTTP server listen on multiple ports?

Tags: python, server, python-requests, webserver

I am trying to create a python server that listens on multiple ports at once, I know I have to create multiple sockets however I am not sure how to accomplish this.
My current server uses the `SimpleHTTPServer` module and listens on Port 8000. However I would like it to also listen on 8001 and 8002.

Here is the current server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging

PORT = 8000

class GetHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


Handler = GetHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have tried to adapt the code to listen on port 8001 and 8002 like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging

PORT = 8000
PORT1 = 8001
PORT2 = 8002

class GetHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


Handler = GetHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT1), Handler)
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT2), Handler)


httpd.serve_forever()
```

However this only listens on the last port (8002).
How can I adapt the script to listen on all 3 ports?